# jQuery trigger asp.net radiobutton click inside of update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some code where the user selects a 'Package' which is highlighted via jquery. How can i cause the asp radiobutton in this div to be clicked and perform its `OnCheckChanged' event?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".package-container").click(function (event) {
            $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-footer').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true).click();
            $(this).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
            $(this).find('.package-footer').addClass('highlight');
        });
    });
```

I have tried this code using the `onclick()` method but it continually loads the page inside of the network tab in chrome is keeps posting the page and eventually lags out without a refresh.

My radiobutton in question is this:

```
<EclipseUI:CustomRadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton_Item" ClientIDMode="AutoID" ToolTip='<%# Eval("SystemValue") %>' GroupName="Package" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_Package_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

How can i make jquery perform the oncheckedchange event of this radiobutton?

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".package-container").click(function (event) {
            $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-footer').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true).click();
            $(this).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
            $(this).find('.package-footer').addClass('highlight');
        });
    });



    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function (event) {
        var currPackage = $("#HF_Package").val();

        $("#" + currPackage).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
        $("#" + currPackage).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-footer').removeClass('highlight');
        $("#" + currPackage).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
        $("#" + currPackage).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
        $("#" + currPackage).find('.package-footer').addClass('highlight');
    });
```

My full jquery code looks like this. The latter part is for the postback to ensure their selected package is highlighted, i get this value from a hidden field and find the div of this value which is the package.

Comment: are you trying to call any function after radio button click or just want to select it?

Comment: I'll add my full jQuery code for the radiobutton and the div it is inside

Comment: This isn't an asp radiobutton is it.

Comment: @DeeMac its a customr adiobutton which inherits everything from the base radiobutton class. the only difference is the name parameter which has been changed to get past the asp.net reapeater naming bug

Comment: are you trying to trigger postback? just call __doPostBack

Comment: @MichaelB. Yeah, I am trying to cause a postback on the click of the radiobutton, so that the oncheckedchanged function fires

Comment: @MichaelB. I have tried adding __DoPostBack inside my document.ready function but after the inital click i cant click the packages again? there is no postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in update panel your DOM elements are replaced with content returned from async postback so event binding is reset.

you need to attach event handlers on 2 events :

```
(function($){ 

  var bindEvents =  function(){
   // bind events here;
  };

  // initial load
  $(document).ready( bindEvents);

  // every async load by update panel
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindEvents);

})(jQuery);
```

for triggering postback, try adding button (you can hide it with css (disply:none) if you don't to display it) then add that button as updatepanel async trigger and call 
_dopostback and pass that button id

```
__doPostBack('<%= TheButton.ClientID %>', '');
```