# "CheckAll" checkbox works only with the first page of asp:Repeater. How to fix?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a Repeater with CheckBoxes:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_users" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_users_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpt_users_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="usersTable">
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">All<br /><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkAll" OnCheckedChanged="checkAll_CheckedChanged"/></th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="c0">
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckSelect" runat="server" /></td>               
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here's a script that I placed right after Repeater control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var repeater1Control = document.getElementById('<%= rpt_users.ClientID %>');
    $('input:checkbox[id$=checkAll]', repeater1Control).click(function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });



    $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).click(function (e) {
        //To uncheck the header checkbox when there are no selected checkboxes in itemtemplate
        if ($('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', repeater1Control).length == 0) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=checkAll]', repeater1Control).removeAttr('checked');
        }
            //To check the header checkbox when there are all selected checkboxes in itemtemplate
        else if ($('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', repeater1Control).length == $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).length) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=checkAll]', repeater1Control).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, It works only at the first page of repeater. If I go to the second page or further, then nothing happens when I press "CheckAll" checkbox in header. How to fix this issue?

Comment: When you go to the second page, is this a post back?  Does your javascript render on the second page?

Comment: Yes, I think it is a post back. I can see my JS at every page in Development Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I in the browser). But it works only at first page.

Comment: What's the html id (rendered in the browser) of the checkAll checkbox on page 2?

Comment: `ctl00_PlhMain_ctl00_rpt_users_ctl00_checkAll` same as at first one.

Comment: are you using update panel ?

Comment: @Michael B., What is it? Actually I work with some kind of CMS, that was developed before me. Some details of it's structure might be unknown for me at this stage. How could I check what you ask?

Comment: does 2nd page come in full postback or partial postback (whole page is not reloaded)

Comment: if it is partial postback, try code in my answer there http://stackoverflow.com/a/25180573/1755374

Comment: @Michael B., seems like it is a partial callback, cause I don't see load progress in browser. Can you tell me, what I exactly have to write in my script? I'm not sure what I have to place in bindEvents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
(function($){ 

  var bindEvents =  function(){
   // bind events here;
    var repeater1Control = document.getElementById('<%= rpt_users.ClientID %>');
    $('input:checkbox[id$=checkAll]', repeater1Control).click(function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });



    $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).click(function (e) {
        //To uncheck the header checkbox when there are no selected checkboxes in itemtemplate
        if ($('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', repeater1Control).length == 0) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=checkAll]', repeater1Control).removeAttr('checked');
        }
            //To check the header checkbox when there are all selected checkboxes in itemtemplate
        else if ($('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', repeater1Control).length == $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]', repeater1Control).length) {
            $('input:checkbox[id$=checkAll]', repeater1Control).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
  };

  // initial load
  $(document).ready( bindEvents);

  // every async load by update panel
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindEvents);

})(jQuery);
```